# Value from form doesn't appear in database properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I just want to transfer the information from a text form into a database, but the value doesn't appear in the database properly. Here's what I have:

**HTML code, for the form:**

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">

    <input type="text" maxlength="150" name="textbox">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO notes (User, Note)
VALUES ('test', '$_POST [textbox]')");

// I also tried writing $_POST ['textbox'] instead; didn't make a difference.

?>
```

However, the output in the database is as follows:

User: **test** 
Note: **Array [textbox]**

How would I be able to correct the value in the Note column (i-e to make it the value entered in the form)?

Answer (score 3):

First off...you had a space between $_POST and ['textbox'];
it shoulda just been $_POST['textbox']...

But also you need to sanitize the data first so...
Try this

```
$input = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['textbox']);

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO notes (User, Note)
VALUES ('test', '$input')");
```

But really you should use PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_* functions...
Google PDO, and learn to do prepared statements.

Here it is with PDO...

```
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);

 $user = 'Test';
 $note = $_POST['textbox'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO notes (User, Note) VALUES (:user,:note)";
 $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':user'=>$user,
              ':note'=>$note));
```

EDIT...
I also noticed your inputs aren't closed, there should be a / at the end of each...

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">

    <input type="text" maxlength="150" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: He is using mysqli, not mysql.

Comment: You can do prepared statements with mysqli. He should use PDO if there's ever a chance he'll change database engines. What other reason is there to use PDO over OOP mysqli?  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Alright, I tried that first code, but ever since, it gives me an error saying that textbox is an invalid index... Which I wasn't getting before. Also thanks for the POD advice, I'll look into it.

Comment: Well you weren't getting anything before, because you had a space between $_POST and ['textbox']  but now that its correct, and it says invalid, something tells me its not being passed from the form......if you just clear out process.php and put <?var_dump($_POST);?> what do you get?

Comment: A blank page... What does that mean?

Comment: That means that when you're entering someting into 'textbox' on the first page, and its going to the second page, the data isnt making it there.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have any idea what could be causing that? Thanks a lot for all the help by the way.

Comment: It still gives the same "undefined index" error... Good point for the input tags though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between $_POST and [textbox]. $_POST is an array. Hence, Array [textbox], ie: ArraySPACE[textbox]

You should remove the space, then look into using prepared statements. You should not use user submitted data directly without sanitizing it first.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO notes (User, Note)
VALUES ('test', '{$_POST['textbox']}')");
```